# Rounded square background shape with cut-out circle in top right

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create list of items which has a design like below,

[image]

The background much have that top right rounded carving for icon to arrange.

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem?

Comment: You cannot create that drawable , even if you could it would be very difficult to . You can take full rounded orange background , then take a circle background around clock and place clock on top of orange background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Try this....

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#c20586"/>
<stroke android:width="5dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

roundcorner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffa800" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

i hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

output:

[image]

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_yellow_radius_10" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_white">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_circles"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle_pink" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

adjust the widths and height according to your requirement